# Matlab break iteration if line execution requires too much time

Tags: matlab, time, break, linear-programming

I run a Matlab code with an iteration loop,  and during each iteration it sample random numbers and uses the function `intlinprog`. My issue is that, due to the large amount of data I provide to the `intlinprog` function and to the stochastic values I assign to part of its variables, some of the iterations take a really long time.

My code is more or less like this:

```
rounds = 1E3;
Total_PF = zeros(rounds,4893);
for i=1:rounds
   i
   cT = zeros (4894,1);
   cT(4894,1) = 1;
   xint = linspace(1,4893,4893);
   xint = xint';
   AT = rand(4,4894);
   beT = ones(4,1);
   lb = zeros(4894,1);
   ub = ones (4894,1);
   ub(4894,1) = Inf;

   [x] = intlinprog(cT,xint,AT,beT,[],[],lb,ub);
   Total_PF(i,:)= (x(1:length(x)-1)');
```

end

Now in the minimal working example I provided, all the iterations are quite fast, but in my real code, sometimes `intlinprog` takes really long time ( I mean hours) to do a single iteration.

Therefore, I was wondering: is there a way to break the `intlinprog` while the `intlinprog` line is being executed? I was thinking that it may be done by modifying the matlab function but first of all I do not know if I am allowed to do it, secondly I am afraid that may be very dangerous.

Comment: A stronger MIP solver may do this much faster.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen what do you mean with a stronger MIP? Which one should I use?

Comment: I meant a stronger solver, that is a solver that can solve the same problem but faster. I think I am on safe ground when I am saying that the fastest currently available solvers include Cplex, Gurobi and Xpress. Some or all of them have Matlab interfaces.

Comment: Thank you @ErwinKalvelagen, I moved to another, more powerful solver and I do not record the freezes I recorded before. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very difficult to do effectively.
You could try using a timer object to watch the value. However, since you are using inherent Matlab functions and not executing external functions, you could set a time limit value and utilize `tic` and `toc` in a `while loop` while you execute the `intlinprog` and checking the value of `toc` against your time limit and `break` your code if `toc` exceeds the limit.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I marked your answer as the chosen choice, even though due to the suggestions provided me by Erwin Kalvelagen in the comments, I moved to another computational tool to handle the MILP and I do not record the freezes I recorded before. Thank you very much